# How to Merge Separate CNNs/Convs in keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am a little new to deep learning/cnn and keras.
I was researching feasibility : 
For example I have two dataset : data_set_1=img_cat_dog dataset and data_set_2=flower_rose_daisy dataset
I have 2 CNNs :
conv_1= .. data_set_1
and train

conv_2= .. data_set_2
and train

And then I have a test data=one picture or video scene which includes cat and rose.
So would it be possible to merge these 2 CNN(conv_1 and conv_2) and then one LSTM, so with one test data(one picture) to describe cat and rose in picture/scene ?

(conv_1 is trained and conv_2 is trained in parallel, after seperate training I would like to merge these conv and connect them to one LSTM )

Comment: you're getting downvoted because its unclear and or a bit broad what you're asking here. Maybe try something out, or write out  a model in keras to demonstrate what you're thinking.

Answer (score 0):

**Pseudo code :**

def create_convnet(img_path='img_cat_dog.png'):
    input_shape = Input(shape=(rows, cols, 1))

```
tower_1 = Conv2D(20, (100, 5), padding='same', activation='relu')(input_shape)
tower_1 = MaxPooling2D((1, 11), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(tower_1)
```

def create_convnet2(img_path='flower_rose_daisy.png'):
    input_shape_2 = Input(shape=(rows, cols, 1))

```
tower_2 = Conv2D(20, (100, 7), padding='same', activation='relu')(input_shape_2)
tower_2 = MaxPooling2D((1, 9), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(tower_2)
```

Training here...

```
merged = keras.layers.concatenate([tower_1, tower_2, tower_3], axis=1)
merged = Flatten()(merged)
```

Or Training here...

(I will write exact code in Keras, so I will try. 
And I will make question more clear also.
)

I try to ask when to train, after merging two CNNs or before merging two CNNs ?
Would it be possible to use two different training dataset also and merge networks ?